# Problem installing software in UNIX (Sun Solaris)

Tags: solaris, software-installation

I am new to UNIX. I have some software which need to be installed in UNIX.

I have below the list of OS provided by a third party software provider. Can anyone help me out: which OS Software will be compatible with Solaris?

For example I want to install `oracle.rpm` for Solaris but Oracle has not provided an RPM for solaris. They have provided RPMs for the below OS.

Which one will be compatible with Sun Solaris?

```
CentOS_CentOS-5/        
Fedora_12/              
Fedora_13/              
RHEL_5/                 
SLES_9/                 
SLE_10_SDK/             
SLE_11_SP1/             
openSUSE_11.3/          
xUbuntu_10.04/
```

Answer (score 4):

Solaris is not a Linux distribution so, if you have binary software which can be installed on any of those operating systems listed (which *are* all Linux distros), it won't install on Solaris.

In fact, unless you're running Solarix/x86, even the lowest binary level is likely to be totally incompatible. The vast majority of Solaris installations we deal with are still Solaris-on-SPARC, which is fundamentally incompatible with x86 operating systems.

If you have the source code, you could possibly compile it on Solaris but:

1. It's not something I'd suggest for a novice; and
2. Solaris is different enough from Linux to cause some fundamental problems (in my experience).

Answer (score 1):

Just try [OpenCSW](http://www.opencsw.org/) which provides tons of third-party software without efforts.

To install Oracle, just download Oracle for Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to install a product from Oracle on Solaris.  What you've listed appear to be what I suspect to be different install procedures/builds for different flavors of Linux.  You'll need to get/download the product from the vendor, or use one of the OSes you have media for.

In the event you want [Oracle 12c on Solaris 11 in 5 steps](http://Tech%20Article:%20Five%20Steps%20for%20Installing%20Oracle%20Database%2012c%20on%20Oracle%20Solaris%2011).

Answer (score -1):

Those are all GNU/Linux distributions.  They're not applications you'd install in Solaris, they're entire operating systems that you'd install *instead* of Solaris.

Comment: i mean i have some software .rpm inside that folders

Comment: @Tapsi: none of those are compatible with a Solaris OS.

Comment: Solaris doesn't use RPM packages.  See if the software you need is actually available as a Solaris package.  Or consider just using Linux instead of Solaris.

Answer (score -1):

Those are all Linux distributions (operating systems), not programs which you install.

If you want to try one of them, just burn the ISO onto a disk and boot it up.

I wouldn't suggest Solaris or any other non-mainstream OS to new users, as it will be a pain to find support. Try Ubuntu 10.10 or 10.04, as that distribution is aimed at newer users.